# SHA512 and custom salt on checkhash - PhalconPHP

Tags: php, hash, phalcon, salt

```
public function beforeSave(){
    $salt = "Acrec_$";
    $hashed = hash('sha512', $salt . $this->password);
    $this->password = $hashed;
}
```

I'm using a custom Salt and custom hash to encrypt the users password, but, now i need to log-in the users.

the Code inside `loginAction();`

```
$this->auth->check([
    'email' => $this->request->getPost('email'),
    'password' => $this->request->getPost('password'),
    'remember' => $this->request->getPost('remember')
]);
```

Comment: Salts are supposed to be unique for each user. Also, you should not be using a single hash round to protect passwords, you should be using an algorithm such as [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) that uses multiple rounds of hashing to make offline cracking infeasible.

Comment: `$salt = "Acrec_$";` you should be putting that in single quotes. The `$` is a special character in php.

Comment: when i use bcrypt it returns a String like this:

string(60) "$2y$08$bk5kV3BpZjlGanJDOEpPUO0CEBpTmlVAo8iCc5O4YsEk1c7004L8i"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In phalcon just use:

```
$password = $this->request->getPost('password');
$user->password = $this->security->hash($password);
```

And

```
$password = $this->request->getPost('password');
$user = Users::findFirst();
if ($this->security->checkHash($password, $user->password)) {
    // any logic here
}
```

By default it's using bcrypt which has salts built-in.

Comment: Link to [phalcon security hash](https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.0/reference/security.html) which seems similar to [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). If it is a better choice than `password_hash`/`password_verify` is unknown.

Comment: It's using password_hash and password_verify anyway. Just OOP wrapper around them with other methods for security things like some randomizer, csrf etc.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), the pair are secure and easy to use.

When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.